# Managing Associations in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around model association in ruby on rails.

Let's say I have a Game model and a GameStatus model.  I want each Game to have one GameStatus and a GameStatus can have many Games.  How would I go about connecting those two.  I have a game_status_id in my Game table migration, and I currently have a belongs_to :game in my GameStatus model.  How do I get the Game model to eagerly load its GameStatus?  And on the other hand, can I use the GameStatus model to get all the Games with that status, preferably filtered by some other Game property?

I'm using Ruby On Rails 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a GameStatus `has_many :games`, then a Game `belongs_to :game_status`. You need to define both sides of the relationship.

Although, I'm racking my brain trying to figure out a meaning to an architecture as you describe... Are you sure it's not *vice versa*? That one Game can have many Statuses, which belong to that Game in turn?

Comment: Game obviously has one status. "started", "finished", etc. But if it is this kind of status, then I'd denormalize it into a field.

Comment: I feel like GameState would have been a better name.  The GameState is something along the lines of "Challenger's Turn" or "Player's Turn".  Just a way to keep track of what is happening at that point in a game.  So each Game would only have 1 of those.  I was under the impression that belongs_to implies that the other side of the relationship held a foreign key reference to the object the belongs_to is defined in.

Comment: Ah, that kind of "game status". I was thinking of, say, each board configuration in game of chess being one "game status" (i.e. one per move in a game). Gotcha. Anyway - @btate, what your last sentence says is incorrect: the side that `belongs_to` has a reference (like a child that `belongs_to` a father has a reference to the father); if the other side held a reference, they would have to hold an array of them (since a father `has_many` children). Thus, the `belongs_to`/`has_many` is always joined through a foreign reference on the object which `belongs_to`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: It will be a field, either way. The only question is if there is a table backing the enumeration or not (in case you want to dynamically change it, or if it supports i18n)

Comment: Gotcha.  That makes sense.  What about eager loading?

Comment: Got it.  I was doing my include => :game_status in my find, but not in my render :json.  So `render :json => game, :include => :game_status` brought it all back.